# In C programming; Given a string, compute recursively (no loops) a new string where all appearances of "pi" have been replaced by "3.14".

Tags: c

My code doesn't work correctly, what did I do wrong? As the title says, it's supposed to create a new string that replaces 'pi' with 3.14. It works allright when I type in pi, but when I type in something like 'pipi' it only returns 3.14 instead of 3.143.14...
Thank you for helping :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char c[50];
char xy(char a[],int b)
{
    if(b>=strlen(a))
        return a;
    else if(a[b]=='p' && a[b+1]=='i'){
        c[b]='3';
        c[b+1]='.';
        c[b+2]='1';
        c[b+3]='4';
        return xy(a,b+4);}
    else if(a[b]!='i') {
        c[b]=a[b];
        return xy(a,b+1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char a[50];
    scanf("%s",&a);
    xy(a,0);
    printf("%s",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Please see [this](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: This screams "homework". The main clue here is "recursively", that means that you'll have a function call itself (or A calls B which calls A, etc). Think about having xy call itself, and add its own result to the call.

Comment: I take it this is homework? No wonder there's a shortage of decent programmers when schools are setting this type of exercise. At least make the required functionality fit better with a recursive solution (exponential, binary tree search, etc..). This is just awful and confusing for newbies. This is an iteration problem not a recursive problem!

Comment: `if(b>=strlen(a))` is expensive. Just test `if(a[b] == '\0')` or just `if(!a[b])`

Comment: I always find these examples of "recursion homework" simply an awful way of teaching recursion. This is not a problem one would *ever* solve recursively (lest it show up on The Daily WTF). Why don't real-world recursion problems ever make it as homework?

Comment: Actually, I've found that compilers do pretty good optimization on these.  I wrote a recursive strlen and strcpy just for good measure to compare against several variations of highly hand-optimized for alignment and word-sized operations, never thinking they would be close, and the recursive ones outperformed all but a couple of hand coded assembly versions almost across the board.  Recursion is just one of those things that decreases readability and compilers used to be bad at optimizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type `pipi`

Here you are passing `b+4`. Actually after first `pi` you need to check for second `pi` so you need to pass `b+2`

```
  return xy(a,b+4);
```

Modify your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could probably be teased into working, but it would be more efficient to forward pointers. One problem with your code is that `scanf("%s", &a)` is going to stop at the first whitespace.

The following rework eliminates the need for returning anything, there is only one direction of flow. It also eliminates the global, 'c'.

Lastly, it does away with need for knowledge of the size of the src string by relying on the fact that C strings are terminated with a nul byte ('\0').

Note: a good optimizer is going to turn this into a loop :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void transform(char* dst, const char* src)
{
    if(!*src) {
        *dst = '\0';
        return;
    }
    if(*src == 'p' && *(src + 1) == 'i') {
        *(dst++) = '3';
        *(dst++) = '.';
        *(dst++) = '1';
        *(dst++) = '4';
        src += 2;  // skip 'pi' in src.
    } else {
        *(dst++) = *(src++);
    }
    transform(dst, src);
}

int main()
{
    char a[64], b[64];
    fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
    transform(b, a);
    printf("%s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/15q17k

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as follows:

```
char xy(char a[],int b, int i)
{
    if(i>=strlen(a))
        return a;
    else if(a[i]=='p' && a[i+1]=='i') {
        c[b]='3';
        c[b+1]='.';
        c[b+2]='1';
        c[b+3]='4';
        return xy(a,b+4, i+2);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, your code is wrong. It is incomplete. Second please format your code and text properly, it is mixed now. Third what do you mean with "you can update the answer like below"? You are the one giving the answer so no updating needed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
include <iostream>
include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char* replace(char* a, char* b) 
{
    int len = strlen(b);

    if(a[0] == '\0') {
      b[len] = '\0';
      return b;
    }

    if(a[0]=='p' && a[1]=='i'){
        b[len + 0]='3';
        b[len + 1]='.';
        b[len + 2]='1';
        b[len + 3]='4';
        b[len + 4] = '\0';
        replace(a + 2,b);
    }

    else {
        b[len + 0]= a[0];//h
        b[len + 1] = '\0';//'\0'
        replace(a + 1, b);//ellopi
    }
}

void transform(char input[])
{
   char *arr=new char[strlen(input) * 2+1];
   arr[0] = '\0';
   strcpy(input, replace(input, arr));
}

int main()
{
    char a[100];
    cin.getline(a,100);
    transform(a);

    cout<<a;

    return 0;
}
```